# Does the Spotify web player (play.spotify.com) user peer-to-peer connections?

Tags: spotify

Does the spotify web player (play.spotify.com) use p2p transfers to supplement the bandwidth available for streaming directly from their own servers? I know their software client used to do that but I wasn't sure about the online version.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Unadvertised-P2P-feature/td-p/398612), **No** (but would be yes for the desktop version).